# Basemap installation on Mac laptop

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, matplotlib-basemap

I know there are several questions about this topic, but I cannot find a clear answer.

I'm trying to install Basemap in my laptop (Mac OS X, v 10.6.8). I'm running Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.0.1.

Python is installed in the following folder: users/myname/anaconda

I've downloaded basemap-1.0.7  into the same folder (users/myname/anaconda), then I follow the instructions from http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html:

To install the GEOS library I open up a terminal and type:

```
cd anaconda/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/
export GEOS_DIR=/user/myname/anaconda
./configure --prefix=$GEOS_DIR
```

Then I get the following error:

```
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/myname/anaconda/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Then, when I try to run `make`; `make install` I get the error:

```
-bash: make: command not found
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Basemap needs to compile GEOS, which is a C library, so you need a C compiler.

Alternatively, just download and install from the Mac OSX binaries provided here: http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/